# KDE 4.8 started to open new windows in a "grid mode"?

Tags: kde

I don't know how, but I appear to have toggled some option that causes KDE to open new windows in a grid mode, and I don't have any idea for how to fix this...

Has anybody seen this before? How can I change this back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the settings for the "grid mode" are here:
System Settings → Window Behavior → Advanced → Tiling
Just disable it there...

I also found the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> which toggles tiling.

P.S. With KDE it is always useful to look through the settings, or just search by some keywords in Kickoff (which I did to answer the question).